# error in compelling xml values

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I do know that xml values have special codes for writing special charecters like `& < >`

However, my code doesn't contain any of these charecters.

```
<string name="scientists_descrption">(26 December 1791  18 October 1871) was an English polymath.He was a mathematician, philosopher, inventor and mechanical engineer, who is best remembered now for originating the concept of a programmable computer.\n Considered a "father of the computer", Babbage is credited with inventing the first mechanical computer that eventually led to more complex designs. His varied work in other fields has led him to be described as "pre-eminent" among the many polymaths of his century.\n Parts of Babbage's uncompleted mechanisms are on display in the London Science Museum. In 1991, a perfectly functioning difference engine was constructed from Babbage's original plans. Built to tolerances achievable in the 19th century, the success of the finished engine indicated that Babbage's machine would have worked.</string>
```

but I still got error in this string.

any help please?

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `'` with backslash, so just replace all occurrences of `'` with `\'`.

```
<string name="scientists_descrption">(26 December 1791  18 October 1871) was an English polymath.He was a mathematician, philosopher, inventor and mechanical engineer, who is best remembered now for originating the concept of a programmable computer.\n Considered a "father of the computer", Babbage is credited with inventing the first mechanical computer that eventually led to more complex designs. His varied work in other fields has led him to be described as "pre-eminent" among the many polymaths of his century.\n Parts of Babbage\'s uncompleted mechanisms are on display in the London Science Museum. In 1991, a perfectly functioning difference engine was constructed from Babbage\'s original plans. Built to tolerances achievable in the 19th century, the success of the finished engine indicated that Babbage\'s machine would have worked.</string>
```

Comment: That's really weird. I've checked it in Eclipse and ADT. Try to paste exactly the text I've put in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your are having an error because you haven't backslashed your double quotes inside the `string`.

`..."father of the computer"...` must be `...\"father of the computer\"...`.

Although you might have the same problem with single quotes.